# How to intersect multiple polygons?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, polygons

I am looking for an algorithm with the following input and output:

Input: A set of polygons in a plane. E.g. P1...Pn and S. (P1...Pn might be concave, S is convex.)

Output: The area of theset of polygons in this plane that equals the difference of S and the union of P1...Pn.

I found algorithms to intersect or merge TWO polygons. But since each of those operations might produce several polygons I createt tons of polygons if I did it naively.

So: How to handle the intersection of multiple polygons?

It would be ok, if all polygons are connected together since only the area is what I am after. My thought was to use directed polygons to simulate holes but then I again have the problem to find out if I have a "minimal representation" as n could blow up. [Do you understand what I am talking about? It's quite strange...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could throw all edges together into a [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).  It may not be optimal (?) but at least you will get the minimal representation you are looking for.

Comment: Incidentally, the use of a sweepline algorithm to intersect two (non)convex polygons is described in [Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html) p.266, among other sources.  This is far superior to partitioning into convex pieces or triangulating.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert each polygon into a bunch of triangles. Once you do that it is fairly easy to find union/intersection/difference between a set of areas since you can perform the same functions trivially on a triangle (result on two triangles may include up to 6 triangles).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: Every iteration may triple the number of polygons. So if I have n triangles I will get about approx n*3^(n-1) triangles... If n rises this will explode. It would be nessesary to "compress" the problem in earlier steps by combining possible polygons or removing empty intersections. So: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach would be decomposing your concave polygons into convex ones. Then intersecting two convex polygons is almost trivial.