# How to calculate the area of multiple polygons?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, area

I posted some days ago this question: [How to intersect multiple polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399711/how-to-intersect-multiple-polygons). Now I implemented a sweep line algorithm as recommended (concrete the one from Martinez, Rueda and Feito).

The result is a set of polygons that do not overlap. But these polygons can contain each other (holes) or touch the boundaries (being a hole or an island polygon).

A picture of what I mean:

[image: a picture of what I mean]

I think this should cover all the special cases; intersections are handled by the sweep line algorithm.

Now I need the area of the polygons (marked gray). My first idea was to add polygon by polygon and to check if they contain each other and use some intelligent selection mechanism to only select the needed polygons. But this generates some O(n^2) algorithm: For each polygon to process, every edge has to be compared to every edge that is already processed.

Not that good. Can you give me a hint how to calculate the total area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard vertex order is counterclockwise for polygons and clockwise for holes. If you store your data using this convention, just compute the area with the standard [polygon area calculation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid). Areas of the holes will be negative.

If you have them in some other order, then you have a problem. Better fix it now.

Comment: The problem is, that the sweepline algorithm does not matter about the orientation. Therefore holes are not stored cw and islands ccw. Do you know of a sweepline algorithm that takes the order into account?

Comment: If your original polygons were all counterclockwise and without holes, the sweepline algorithm should give the correct orientation for island and holes. Keep direction with each segment and never change it. When a segment is divided by an intersection, the two smaller segments inherit the direction. The holes will become counterclockwise automatically.

Comment: In fact: No that's not true. You are talking about one particular sweepline algorithm. There are several. The algorithm I found and implemented finishes by trying to find chains of polygon edges, while the orientation of the chains do not depend on the original direction of the chains. But I will check if I can modify the algorithm.

Comment: You need to remember the original orientation of each segment. When your algorithm finishes the work, just reorient the chains according to the original orientation. It will be consistent (you won't get a chain with two segments looking in different directions).